# What dimension should the cuRAND initialization kernel have

Tags: cuda

I am working on a program in which there are two main kernels.

Due to the impact on performances, each kernel has its own dimensions. Thus I have 2 different block and grid sizes (whose values cannot be known at compile time).

Both kernels need to use the cuRAND library, so before a third kernel is launched to initialize the cuRAND state on the device.

My question comes when I need to choose the dimensions of this kernel.

Let's say I have for kernel 1 and 2:

```
block_size_1 = 256
grid_size_1 = 10
block_size_2 = 512
grid_size_2 = 2
```

For the cuRAND initialization kernel, should I use the largest sizes (`10*512`), or the highest number of threads (`10*256`)?

Comment: You should read the [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/curand/index.html). Your question is unclear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick the biggest kernel size, because that is the maximum number of cuRand generators that you'll use. You can easyly evaluate the size you need using something like

```
__host__ void fun(){
    curandState * randState;
    int myCurandSize = ((block_size1 * grid_size1) > (block_size2 * grid_size2))? Block_size1 * Grid_size1 : Block_size2 * Grid_size2);
    error = cudaMalloc((void **)&randState, myCurandSize * sizeof(curandState));
    if (error == cudaErrorMemoryAllocation){
        cudaDeviceReset();
        return 1;
    }
    setup_cuRand <<<1, myCurandSize>>> (randState, unsigned(time(NULL)));

    //Don't forget to free the space
    cudaFree(randState);
}

__global__ void setup_cuRand(curandState * state, unsigned long seed)
{
    int id = threadIdx.x;
    curand_init(seed, id, 0, &state[id]);
}
```

Edit: I was asumming that `block_size * grid_size` will not go over the maximum thread limit, otherwise, you can do the same but keeping aswell the grid and block dimension and launching that number of threads `setup_curand<<<x, y>>>(...);`